# Vue : Type 'Ref<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, yup, vee-validate, pinia

I am using Vue3 , type script , composition and vee-validate4 and Pinia store all together

this is user register from.

**views/register**

```
const schema = yup.object({
  email: yup.string().required().email("لطفا ! ایمیل معتبر وارد کنید ."),
  password: yup.string().required().min(8, "کلمه عبور باید حداقل هشت کاراکتر باشد ."),
});

const { errors, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  validationSchema: schema,
});

const { value: email } = useField('email');
const { value: password } = useField('password');
```

and i have a method here for register

**views/register**

```
async function add() {
  try {
    const res = await useAuthStore().register({email,password})
      } catch (err: any) {}
}
```

But , here I have a **typescript** error .

[image]

and my **Pinia store** is like this

```
actions: {
    register( user:ICreateUser) {
      return AuthService.create(user).then(
        response => {
          this.status.loggedIn = false;
          return Promise.resolve(response.data);
        },
        error => {
          this.status.loggedIn = false;
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    }
},
```

How cam I fix Typescript errors ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add type to `useField` ⇒ take a look at [useField.ts#L76](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/83c2e1752b2b020926af3218e7bcd2c03763714e/packages/vee-validate/src/useField.ts#L76)

Try something like.

```
const { value: email } = useField<string>('email')
```

Comment: now it says 
Type 'Ref<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Comment: @kevin Ref<string> means that you should pass `email.value` rather just `email` to `register`; `register({ email: email.value, password: password.value })`.